# ISO 9141-2 protocol overview

Tags: obd

Is there a free overview of the ISO 9141-2 (K-Line) protocol?  I'm looking for basic handshaking info (master control), structure of a frame, etc.

The only information I could find was a for-sale document from the ISO standards body.  I don't need electrical details, just protocol overview.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/handmade0octopus/ds2

Comment: Also this: https://www.obdclearinghouse.com/Files/viewFile?fileID=1380

Comment: An initial Google search returned many hits, using 'ISO 9141-2 (K-Line) protocol' as key words. I would presume this isn't proprietary to any vehicle manufacturer and available on the internet from almost any good source of info; electronic sites sterilizing in OBD II protocols/pinouts, some vehicle manufacturers with extensive service manuals, electronic communication sites able to describe in details serial and parallel comms (OBD II,  canbus), etc. If you have difficulty finding these sites, I or anyone else can post links to them.